# How to filter records when foreign table has combined primary key in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have two tables which are interlinked:

Table #1: CheckList

```
ID_CHECKLIST(PK) |  NAME_CHECKLIST |  VERSION(PK)
1                   XYZ               1.0.0
1                   XYZ               1.1.0
1                   XYZ               1.2.0
2                   PQR               1.0.0
3                   ABC               1.1.0
```

Table #2: Machine_CHECKLIST

```
ID_MACHINE |  ID_CHECKLIST(Foreign Key) |  VERSION(Foreign)
1              1                           1.2.0
1              3                           1.1.0
2              1                           1.1.0
```

Now I want to get all of the remaining checklist that are not included in ID_MACHINE = 1

So my query is like this:

```
SELECT 
    ID_CHECKLIST, NAME_CHECKLIST, VERSION
FROM
    CHECKLIST 
WHERE
    (ID_CHECKLIST NOT IN (SELECT MC.ID_CHECKLIST 
                          FROM MACHINE_CHECKLIST MC 
                          WHERE MC.ID_MACHINE = '1'))
    OR (VERSION NOT IN (SELECT MC.VERSION 
                        FROM MACHINE_CHECKLIST MC  
                        WHERE MC.ID_MACHINE = '1'))
```

This query does not return proper results.

I pass `ID_MACHINE` dynamically. I cannot pass Version and that's the problem.

What am I doing wrong in the query?

Comment: A relational table **NEVER** has two primary keys - you might have a primary key made up from more than one column - but you never have two primary keys....

Comment: updated the title with combined primary key

Comment: What's your expected result here? Is it just the `2, PQR, 1.0.0` row or should it also include the other *versions* (1.0.0, 1.1.0) of checklist `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to LEFT JOIN the tables on the composite key, and look for a NULL value on the right table in the join. This will tell you where you are missing data.

```
SELECT 
    CheckList.ID_CHECKLIST, CheckList.NAME_CHECKLIST, CheckList.VERSION
FROM
    Machine_CHECKLIST 
LEFT JOIN CheckList ON Machine_Checklist.ID_CheckList = Checklist.ID_CheckList 
    AND Machine_Checklist.Version = CheckList.Version
WHERE 
   ID_Machine = 1 AND CheckList.ID_Checklist IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try an Inner Join. You don't have to return columns of both tables, but you can use both tables for filtering.

```
SELECT 
    CHECKLIST.ID_CHECKLIST, CHECKLIST.NAME_CHECKLIST, CHECKLIST.VERSION
FROM
    CHECKLIST INNER JOIN Machine_CHECKLIST ON CHECKLIST.ID_CHECKLIST = Machine_CHECKLIST.ID_CHECKLIST AND CHECKLIST.VERSION = Machine_CHECKLIST.VERSION
WHERE
    Machine_CHECKLIST.ID_MACHINE <> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It gives you Checklist that are not in Machine_CHECKLIST:

```
declare @CheckList table(ID_CHECKLIST int, NAME_CHECKLIST varchar(50), VERSION varchar(50))
insert into @CheckList(ID_CHECKLIST, NAME_CHECKLIST, VERSION) values
(1, 'XYZ', '1.0.0')
, (1, 'XYZ', '1.1.0')
, (1, 'XYZ', '1.2.0')
, (2, 'PQR', '1.0.0')
, (3, 'ABC', '1.1.0')

declare @Machine_CHECKLIST table(ID_MACHINE int, ID_CHECKLIST int, VERSION varchar(50))
insert into @Machine_CHECKLIST(ID_MACHINE, ID_CHECKLIST, VERSION) values
(1, 1, '1.2.0')
, (1, 3, '1.1.0')
, (2, 1, '1.1.0')

Select cl.* From @CheckList cl 
Left Join @Machine_CHECKLIST mc On mc.ID_CHECKLIST = cl.ID_CHECKLIST And mc.VERSION = cl.VERSION
Where mc.ID_MACHINE is null
```

Output:

```
ID_CHECKLIST    NAME_    CHECKLIST  VERSION
1               XYZ             1.0.0
2               PQR             1.0.0
```

Comment: You dont pass ID_MACHINE. There can be many ID_MACHINE. I need to pass ID_MACHINE to get missing checklist for that machine from other table.